# See disk disk information Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, raid, windows-server-2012, windows-server

This should not be this difficult, but I can not figure out how to see what/how many drives are being used for the server, and how they are configured (RAID ?).

I THINK I have 7 physical drives (all 1TB) but I don't know that for sure and there has got to be a way to see how many drives are connected using either `Server Manager` or `Disk Management`. [image]

Where is `Disk 1` and `Disk 2`?

`Disk 5` is a USB connected drive.

Here is the view I get from `Server Manager`:[image]
It looks like `Number 0` and `Number 3` are set up as `RAID` but how do I know what sort of `RAID` and how many disks are being used in each?

Any help finding any information about how many physical drives (and their sizes) are connected and what sort of RAID is set up, would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since those disks are part of a Dell PERC RAID controller, the configuration must be accessed through the Dell Open Manage Server Administrator webpage. Here is a guide with screen shots showing what it should look like: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/118749-expanding-a-raid-array-with-a-perc-h710-adapter

### Summary

1. Install the new hard drive(s) in the available slots in the chassis
2. Launch the Dell OpenManage Server Administrator
3. Navigate to the Storage menu and expand the PERC H710 Adapter to locate the physical disks, which should show a Ready status (make note of the IDs)

[image: Step 3]

4. Click on the Virtual Disks menu option and locate the Array that will be expanded. Select the Reconfigure option from the Available Tasks menu

[image: Step 4]

5. Click the Execute button for the Reconfigure task

[image: Step 5]

6. Reconfigure Virtual Disk step 1 of 3 - locate/select the physical disks to add to the array and continue

[image: Step 6]

7. Reconfigure Virtual Disk step 2 of 3 - select the RAID level and continue

[image: Step 7]

8. OK to the Message from webage after verifying that the OS supports the new size of the Array

[image: Step 8]

9. Reconfigure Virtual Disk step 3 of 3 - confirm the settings and click Continue/Finish

[image: Step 9]

10. Monitor the status on the Virtual Disks page - it should display "reconstructing" with a % complete. Depending on the size of the Array, the process may take **several hours or even days** to complete.

[image: Step 10]

11. After the process has completed, verify that the Array size has changed

[image: Step 11]

12. To make the new disk space available in Windows, launch **Server Manager** and select **Disk Management** under Storage. These instructions are based on **Windows Server 2008 R2**
13. Locate the Disk/Partition where the new unallocated space has been added. Right click the partition and select Extend Volume

[image: Step 13]

14. Confirm the proper disk is selected and the amount of space to be added and click Next

[image: Step 14]

15. Review the change in Disk Managment to verify the settings have applied

[image: Step 15]